# HTML5 DeviceAPIs Not working (Returns null)

Tags: javascript, android, html

I Have this code `window.ondeviceorientationabsolute = (e) => console.log(e);`

In both devices (PC and Cellphone) it does output `{ alpha: null, gamma: null, beta: null }`

Im a bit confused, i never used device apis before and i dont know if there is some permissions missing

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: See the glaring red box at the top? > Non-standard
This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Comment: Try using: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/ondeviceorientation

Comment: Hi, thanks for response

The behavior is the same for `window.ondeviceorientation`, is that feature non-standart too? isnt there any sure way of manage device orientation in browsers right now?

Answer (score 0):

window.ondeviceorentationabsolute does not really have any support based on [this developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/ondeviceorientationabsolute)

Comment: Hi, thanks for response :D

ondeviceorientation (Not ondeviceorientationabsolute) shows me the same values, and idk what to do, i searched a lot and didnt find any answer to it, maybe my cellphone doesnt have sensors?

Comment: What browsers are you testing?

Have you tried the jQuery version just to see what it does? https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/

Comment: Google Chrome, Last versions, i gonna check and i tell u what's up

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The API Returns null when the device does not have the respective sensor.